# Combine php strings with substr and strpos into one string

Tags: php, arrays, string, substr, strpos

Not sure if this has been asked but what's the best way to combine three strings into one string. I tried adding an array but it didn't work.

My strings are:
`$linktitle = get_the_title();
$linkt = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, ' —'));
$linkt2 = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, ' &#8211;'));
$linkt3 = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, ' |'));`

Example `$linktitle` outputs:

> Facebook Creates YouTube-Like Video Feature Inside Facebook | Re/code
>   WNYC to Open New Podcast Division – The New York Times

My attempt at combination didn't work:
`$linkall = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, array(' —', &#8211;',' |')));`

What I would like to accomplish is combine `—`, `&#8211;`, and `|` into an array like in the above example (if possible).

Comment: If you're using an array, can use `implode()` to do this.

Comment: You're not making sense. Combine how? Explain more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please also include an example of what the content of `$linktitle` is.

Comment: @PedroLobito Clearly not since in the example the array is inside strops and has nothing to do with the three outputs. I can guess the attempt, but the question should be clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using implode() on the array containing your strings?

Something like

```
$pieces = array($string1, $string2, $string3);
$result = implode('', $pieces);
```

In your case perhaps this makes more sense:

```
$pieces=array();
$pieces[] = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, ' —'));
$pieces[] = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, ' &#8211;'));
$pieces[] = substr($linktitle, 0, strpos($linktitle, ' |'));
$result = implode('', $pieces);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you have missed one quote before `&#8211;`

```
strpos($linktitle, array(' |', '&#8211;',' |')));
```